# mixed normal page css with ember handlebar css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, view, ember.js

## html.erb template:

```js
<div class="container">    
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="sentence">content</script>
</div>
```

## but checked firebug, it becomes

```js
<div class="container"></div>

<div id="ember299" class="ember-view">
  blablabla.....
</div>
```

So, the problem is the script not included by container property

Comment: have you called the `Handlebars.compile(source);` - http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Shouldn't your container div go inside the view's parent template? Or the application template if it's containing everything?

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="container">
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="sentence">
    content
  </script>
</body>
```

Template without `id` is application template.

Comment: don't use handlebars for all of the pages

Comment: @Daniel, i'm not sure if it's possible. Application templates are appended to the application container (body by default), not rendered inline.

Answer (score 1):

## application.html.erb

```js
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 28px;">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
```

## index.html.erb

```js
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="sentence">content</script>
```

## And then checked firebug, it becomes

```js
<div class="container"></div>

<div id="ember299" class="ember-view">
  blablabla.....
</div>
```

## Use  yield

, not {{outlet}}